# Localization property of spherical harmonics on incomplete spheres

Tags: inner-products, dirac-delta, eigenfunctions, spherical-harmonics

This question follows from another question I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3939714/110500).

I am currently trying to read [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/0008083.pdf) paper and I am having difficulty in understanding the interpretations of eq. 7 which are given in lines immediately after the equation. It would be very helpful if you can provide hints on what they mean and also the calculation of the $v_i$ and $\lambda_i$.

As I understand, the point that the author is trying to make is that eigenvectors are localized in either the partial sky or the sky which is masked. But I am unable to follow how the inference is derived.

Any help in this regards would be appreciated.

**Update 1 Jan 2021**
So, here is the math that I did.The integral in equation 7 of the paper that I linked to goes like this,
$$ \int_{S'} v_i(\pmb{\hat{r}}')\delta(\pmb{\hat{r}}-\pmb{\hat{r}}')d\Omega' = \lambda_iv_i(\pmb{\hat{r}})$$
So, the unit vector $\pmb{\hat{r}}$ can point to any direction (in the partial sky $S'$ covered or in the cut sky $S-S'$. The paragraph immediately after this equation mentions that for a given eigenvector, this equation is true for any direction $\pmb{\hat{r}}$. Now, if we take that the $\pmb{\hat{r}}$ is in the partial sky $S'$, then the integral (due to the dirac delta function would just be 1 at the location when $\pmb{\hat{r}}$=$\pmb{\hat{r}}'$ and zero at all other directions which just reduces the equation to, $$v_i(\pmb{\hat{r}}) = \lambda_iv_i(\pmb{\hat{r}})$$, which implies that $v_i(\pmb{\hat{r}}) \neq 0$ but $\lambda_i = 1$. On the other hand, when $\pmb{\hat{r}}$ \neq $\pmb{\hat{r}}'$ then the dirac delta on the left hand side evaluates to zero, hence $$\lambda_iv_i(\pmb{\hat{r}}) = 0$$
In the first case, it is rather easy to see that $\lambda_i$ is 1. But,  I am unable to understand all the other results and constraints of $v_i(\pmb{\hat{r}})$. I cant use $v_i(\pmb{\hat{r}})$ for the two directions together because they are in principle different directions. So, how do I get the result of the paper that, for cut region ($S-S'$) $v_i(\pmb{\hat{r}}) = 0$ and $\lambda_i = 1$ and in the partial covered region, $S'$, $v_i(\pmb{\hat{r}}) = 0$ and $\lambda_i = 0$.

Comment: Hi @epimorphic. Thanks for the comment and sorry for being away for this long. I got busy with other tasks of my research. So, I did the math you suggested and I am updating my results and the underlying question in an edit in the post. Would be very helpful for me if you could give it a quick look. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the Dirac delta, the evaluation of the integral separates into the two cases, depending on whether $\hat{}$ is in the partial sky or not:
$$
\lambda_i v_i(\hat{})
= \int_{S'} v_i(\hat{}') \, \delta(\hat{} - \hat{}') \, \mathrm{d}\Omega'
= \begin{cases} 
    v_i(\hat{}) & \text{if $\hat{} \in S'$} \\
    0           & \text{if $\hat{} \notin S'.$}
  \end{cases}
$$
The key, as the paper suggests, is that this equation holds for every $\hat{}$ in the full sky $S$, as $v_i$ is supposed to be an eigenfunction of the operator with eigenvalue $\lambda_i$. The $\hat{} \in S'$ case of the equation, which can be written perhaps more clearly as $(\lambda_i - 1) v_i(\hat{}) = 0$, implies that either

(a) $\lambda_i = 1$

or

(b) $v_i = 0$ for all $\hat{} \in S'$,

while the $\hat{} \notin S'$ case implies either

(c) $\lambda_i = 0$

or

(d) $v_i = 0$ for all $\hat{} \notin S'$.

Since the zero function is not considered an eigenfunction, the only compatible pairs of possibilities are (a)+(d), or (b)+(c), as claimed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to write the explanation. Could explain the last line and the resultant argument; this is actually the part of the question where I get stuck. In principle, the two directions are different. They either belong in the $S'$ or they don't. My confusion is with what argument can the two results be combined? Also, what exactly does it mean that the eigen vector are "localized" in either the $S-S'$ and $S'$.

Comment: Hello. Sorry for the extremely delayed response. The integral equation leads to $(\lambda_i - 1) v_i(\hat{}) = 0$ pointwise for every $\hat{} \in S'$, and $\lambda_i v_i(\hat{}) = 0$ also pointwise for every $\hat{} \in S \setminus S'$, with the key that $\lambda_i$ is the same for every $\hat{} \in S$. If $v_i(\hat{}) \neq 0$ for some $\hat{} \in S'$, then the first equation implies that $\lambda_i = 1$. If you then use this value in the $\hat{} \in S \setminus S'$ equation, then $v_i(\hat{}) = 0$ for every $\hat{} \in S \setminus S'$.

Comment: On the other hand, if $v_i(\hat{}) = 0$ for every $\hat{} \in S'$, then to have a nonzero eigenfunction we must have $v_i(\hat{}) \neq 0$ for some $\hat{} \in S \setminus S'$. Then $\lambda_i v_i(\hat{}) = 0$ implies that $\lambda_i = 0$.

Comment: A function being localized in some subset $A$ means that the function is zero outside of $A$. If you think of the correspondence of spherical harmonic functions to probabilistic mass distributions, it means all of the mass lies in $A$, and none outside.